# Effective way to count the API calls in an API service

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, relational-database, fastapi

I am asking this question in the context of DRF but this can be generalized too. We are maintaining an API service where we are serving 1K+ real-time requests. In the current scenario, we are counting the API calls in real-time, i.e. we are updating the database column of API calls count against the user for each API call.

But is there an effective method? For example, logging the API calls somewhere else and then updating the database after a few minutes? Or is this fine what we are doing at the moment? How large-scale API services might be handling this? No specific content is available on the web for this problem.

Comment: The 1K+ realtime requests, are per day, per hour, per minute or per second?

Comment: @lsabi 1K+ concurrent requests. You can say per second.

Comment: Then I'd say, a relational database is not enough. Key-value datastores (e.g. redis, rocksdb) can be used to count api calls of clients. You can then verify the number of total requests at each call. Usually that's the strategy if you have so many requests per second.

Comment: @lsabi Thank you so much. This sounds to be a potential solution.

Comment: You can write a service which counts the requests from the logs. This way you have no overhead on the request itself. The service can keep on running in the background to read logs and increment the number of requests.

Comment: Is your API on a distributed cluster or servers?

Comment: @raxetul We were using a single dedicated box. Now we are moving to Docker Swarm where we will be having a cluster setup.

Answer (score 3):

If your application is writing its log to `stdout` you can easily connect it to a log database, like Elasticsearch, and then count the number of requests. You can also create very detailed dashboards that show your users are using your API.

You don't even need to read the output of your application server if you use a web server like NGINX to serve your API. You can pipe its `stdout` log into the database. Whatever the source, having an external process read directly from `stdout` will be more performant than any write operation you do on the application layer.

Treating your logs as event streams is one of the 12 factors described on the "Twelve-Factor App" methodology. You can find more information regarding this methodology on its website:

https://12factor.net/

Answer (score 1):

Redis is an in-memory key-value data store, so it can retrieve data very quickly. It’s also pretty straightforward to implement **rate limiting with Redis and validate number of API calls**. i.e.

1. Store a key like a user’s IP address
2. Increment the number of calls made from that IP

Redis [Link](https://redis.io/commands/incr/#pattern-rate-limiter-1)

Redis Labs [Link](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-5-using-redis-for-application-support/5-2-counters-and-statistics/5-2-1-storing-counters-in-redis/)

Comment: But if you use docker and several copies of the same app in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend you to implement this at the application level, instead, use network middleware to do this.

Like @guzmonne said, you can read Nginx logs directly or with the help of some tools like [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/beats/filebeat)/[Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/logstash).

In my company, we are using Filebeat to collect logs (not only API calls) from containers (300+ nodes in several Kubernetes clusters) and other standalone services, all of them go to an [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch/service?ultron=MS-EL-B-Trials-AMER-NA-Exact&blade=Bing-s&hulk=cpc&Device=c&thor=elasticsearch&msclkid=e365605807d61dc3653a00f25a345bf2) cluster where logs are analyzed.

We do not count API calls, but we do care about the fail rate, there are some [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/) rules to send alerts when there are too many non-200 HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Django, so my advice would be to leverage Memcached here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/

Memcached is an in-memory storage that works very well with Django and that is simpler (but also has less features) than Redis. Memcached makes sure your counter is synchronized across all your Python processes, which is crucial for a Django server.

You could increment counters that track API calls using `cache.incr()`, and for each user request check the counters with `cache.get()`.

As Memcached is "in-memory", data are not going to stay forever, so additionally you could increment a counter in DB **asynchronously** (you don't want to block your user requests for that). In order to make DB counter incrementation more efficient you should use `F()` expressions (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).